# Grub: Difference between (hd0) and (ata0)

Tags: grub2, grub

Grub used to display `(ata0) (ata0,msdos1) ...` when I enter `ls` in the prompt. Now it switched to `(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) ...` Can someone explain what the difference between the two is and if there is a setting for that?

Comment: There are two completely different questions it seems. And the more important (I guess) one has no relation at all to the title. It is probably better to delete the second part from the question and make it (with a more detailed explanation) a separate question.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device names with `hd` in them are your disk devices as presented by the system firmware, whether that firmware is BIOS or UEFI.

The device names with `ata` refer to direct ATA support, i.e. GRUB driving the disk controller directly without involving the system firmware at all. [The GNU GRUB manual says:](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Platform-limitations.html#Platform-limitations)

> Direct ATA/AHCI support allows to circumvent various firmware limitations but isn’t needed for normal operation except on baremetal ports.

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me an explanation on IRC..

- hd0 means grub is using boot firmware to load the drive
- ata0 means grubs native disk drivers are being used.

To get ata0, simply run `grub-install --disk-module=native /dev/sdX ...`